# Python - How can I read a CSV created by a HTML5 Export Button into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am able to read a CSV file with an associated URL directly into Python using the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
URL = 'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv'
pd.read_csv(URL)
```

However, I would similarly like to read CSV files created by an HTML5 Export-Button directly into Python3 (as opposed to downloading the file locally and uploading it to Python).

For example, I would like the CSV file created by clicking the 'CSV' button on this webpage to be read into Python directly as a Pandas DataFrame:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html
[Button Location is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9LEE.png)

I have tried doing this using a combination of Selenium, BeautifulSoup and Pandas in Python3 but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the buttons executes JavaScript and there aren't any URL. But you can use [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) function to load the data (they are in `<table>` form inside the page).

For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html'

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   Name                       Position         Office  Age  Start date      Salary
0           Tiger Nixon               System Architect      Edinburgh   61  2011/04/25    $320,800
1       Garrett Winters                     Accountant          Tokyo   63  2011/07/25    $170,750
2            Ashton Cox        Junior Technical Author  San Francisco   66  2009/01/12     $86,000
3          Cedric Kelly    Senior Javascript Developer      Edinburgh   22  2012/03/29    $433,060
4            Airi Satou                     Accountant          Tokyo   33  2008/11/28    $162,700
5    Brielle Williamson         Integration Specialist       New York   61  2012/12/02    $372,000
6       Herrod Chandler                Sales Assistant  San Francisco   59  2012/08/06    $137,500
7        Rhona Davidson         Integration Specialist          Tokyo   55  2010/10/14    $327,900
8         Colleen Hurst           Javascript Developer  San Francisco   39  2009/09/15    $205,500
9           Sonya Frost              Software Engineer      Edinburgh   23  2008/12/13    $103,600

... and so on.
```

Comment: This works thanks! Does this only work because the table exists on the same page as the button, or all export buttons must have the table available on the same page?

Comment: @saaabotage Clicking on the export buttons runs javascript, that export data from `<table>` to single blob (excel, csv, pdf,...) and sends it to user. So yes, the data needs to be on the same page as buttons (or the button loads the data via Ajax call - but this is not the case)